# How can I verify that my application won't download to android which hasn't BLE

Tags: android, google-play, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing a smartphone application which must connect using BLE to a device in order to do its functionality.

How can I verify that my application won't be download available for mobiles which does not support BLE through google play / app store ?

Thanks

Comment: <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/> will ensure that device have bluetooth. 
For more detail refer https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use this in the manifest for this purpose

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Bluetooth Low Energy](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html)

```
    If you want to declare that your app is available to BLE-capable devices only, include the following in your app's manifest:

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
```